# Joomla Editor: select image looks ugly (no css?)

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

When I want to insert an image in an article, the modal where I select an image is very ugly. It seems there is no CSS which makes the modal more beautiful.

[image: Modal where I select an image]
In my index file I've got the following CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
```

I'm using Joomla! 3.6.5. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: A recent update may be the cause. Clearing the Joomla cache and the cache on your web browser often helps.

Comment: Browser cache does not change anything... when i want to clear the joomla cache i got the error message "The cachelite Cache Storage is not supported on this platform." :( the cache and admin/cache directory is writeable according the system informations...

Comment: please provide the link to your page so that we can see the issue

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful troubleshooting steps:

1. Clear all caches - On your Browser and Joomla's. Also check if your hosting provider has any other persisting cache mechanisms in place.
2. To escape from the "... **Cache Storage is not supported on this platform issue**", you can edit directly your `configuration.php` file and set the `$cache_handler` variable to another setting, like `'file'`.

   ```
   public $cache_handler = 'file';
   ```
3. ... and could also help if you set the cache off temporary:

   ```
   public $caching = '0';
   ```
4. If with all caches cleared, you still get the broken layout issue - then this likely is caused by a php error. A php error (fatal error somewhere) will stop the execution which could lead to incomplete rendering - broken layouts, missing assets etc.

Php errors can be produced from corrupted files, an incomplete update, or other old outdated code somewhere, or even by files that should be where they are - think also a hacked site - Enable error reporting - make sure that any errors are printed/logged in any case - and start debugging to see if this is the case.